# Convert file to HTML entitites

Tags: php

Is there are way to convert the contents of a file into html entities?

The file has header information formatted as: .

i.e. `##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">`

Right now the output just looks like:`##INFO=`

Is there a way to keep the html-like tags and have php output exactly how what it says/how it is formatted in the text file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `htmlentities()` function, which will HTML-escape text.

Comment: I'm trying to use it on an inputted file i.e. htmlentities($filename) and have the contents of the file be HTML-escaoed. Right now, htmlentities() only HTML-escapes the file name..which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlenities ();

You need  a valid character in the default ISO-8859-1 character set, so it's not decoded. Define UTF-8 as the output charset and it will decode:

```
echo html_entity_decode('html', ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If at all possible, you should avoid HTML entities to begin with.